# Error while compiling Angular 2 application in visual studio 2015

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I followed all the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html) for "VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART" , and I have also installed "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" which is not mentioned in the document. I am using Visual studio Community 2015

Now when I build the project , it shows below error

> "tsc.exe" exited with code 1" in file "Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" file.

And in "Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" file it displays

> The element 'Target' in namepace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invaid child element
>   'VsTsc'

Below is my tsconfig.json file content.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Any idea what could be the reason for this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed wrong version of typescript, instead of installing "TypeScript 2 for Visual Studio 2015", I had installed "TypeScript 1.8.4 for Visual Studio 2015", that's the reason for error.